# How can I create a bar chart that has cone at the bottom using chartjs and angular

Tags: angular, chart.js

I want to create a bar chart where the bar has a cone at bottom. Like semi-diamond shape where the top part is flat but the bottom has a pointy cone where it touches the x-axis

I am new to chartjs, was unable to really understand how to proceed